# Unable to send Authorization Header

Tags: angular, jwt

I tried to send a request with an authorization header using Angular 8 HttpClient and auth0 angular jwt to .NET core 3 but the header was not set.
code for service
[image: code for service]

code for app module config
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an external library for your needs.

You should rather look on the interceptor concept: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

An exemple :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService, private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const token = this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken') || this.sessionStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
    if (!!token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```